# Why doesn't the Windows XP installer give me the option to format the hard disk?

Tags: windows-xp, formatting, windows-installation

I'm trying to re-install Windows XP on my computer which only has 1 partition (`C:`).
The problem comes up when there is no format option during the installation process.

I'd like to know how could I get the format option back, if anyone could point me to the solution I'd be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the option during the installation process where you delete the existing partition first?

Comment: more details please, are you trying to install xp using the windows installer or did you BOOT from cd?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the installer while Windows has booted? Make sure you're running the installer from the CD on boot and have your BIOS start-up settings configured such that the CD drive is at a higher boot priority.

The screen you should be looking for is the following, where you would hit <kbd>D</kbd>:

[image]